# Symfony 3 update Action

Tags: symfony

In my project, foreign key should hidden in the form type and have default value so the first id in the table refernced.
In the New Action all good but is in the update action that I block.
I've tried like tkis to give default value for my foreign key in update but It don't works, I have an error: `Expected argument of type "AppBundle\Entity\Cursus", "string" given`

```
public function editAction(Request $request, Etudiant $etud)
{
    $deleteForm = $this->createDeleteForm($etud);
    $editForm = $this->createForm('AppBundle\Form\EtudiantType', $etud);
    $editForm->handleRequest($request);

    $first = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository(Cursus::class)->findOneBy([]);
    $etud->setIdcursus($first);

    if ($editForm->isSubmitted() && $editForm->isValid()) {
        $this->getDoctrine()->getManager()->flush();

        return $this->redirectToRoute('etudiant_edit');
    }

    return $this->render('etudiant/edit.html.twig', array(
        'etudiant' => $etud,
        'edit_form' => $editForm->createView(),
        'delete_form' => $deleteForm->createView(),
    ));
}
```

**EDIT**

Symfony 3.3.10

form Type

```
$builder->add('nom')
->add('prenom')
->add('adresse')
->add('matricule')
->add('domaine')
->add('idcursus', HiddenType::class);
```

**The problem**

The wrong is in my idcursus whom should hidden and have default value(the first id in cursus entity).

Comment: Please update your question with the version of Symfony you are using. And please share your `createForm` method. And have you checked where the Exception is thrown?

Comment: I've already edit this, thanks!

Comment: Somewhere in your code a method expects a `Cursus` object, but you give a string. Can you find the line where it's going wrong?

Comment: I don't know where is wrong because is it the crud generate with symfony, I've just add the line `$first = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository(Cursus::class)->findOneBy([]);
    $etud->setIdcursus($first);` but even if with or not this line exist the error persist,

Comment: Maybe the __toString function in the entity class??

Comment: The error message is thrown somewhere, try to find out which line.

Comment: Can you check the value of $first var and make shure is the expected? Make a dump. The exception is very clear, you are passing a string

Comment: var_dump($first) give me the id of the entity cursus,